# Deepcopy of a Matrix SageMath

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, deep-copy, sage

I am creating a deepcopy of a Matrix in SageMath.

```
import copy
A = Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]).augment(Matrix.identity(2), subdivide=True)
B = copy.deepcopy(A)
print A
print B
```

Gives me:

```
[1 2|1 0]
[3 4|0 1]

[1 2 1 0]
[3 4 0 1]
```

What is the correct way to deepcopy a matrix *with* the subdivision? Do I have to use:

```
B.subdivide(*A.subdivisions())
```

SageMath version 7.2, Release Date: 2016-05-15

Comment: same on `SageMath version 7.3, Release Date: 2016-08-04`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by tmonteil at https://ask.sagemath.org/question/36134/deepcopy-of-a-matrix-sagemath/?answer=36137#post-id-36137

It seems that sage has a custom method

```
__copy__
```

but not a custom method

```
__deepcopy__
```